# Core Data: make object-by-object copy of database

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

I would like to make a backup copy of my Core Data database, without using either the File Manager to make a copy of the sqlite file, or using the Persistent Store Coordinator's migratePersistentStore method (for reasons that are too long to explain here). What I want to do is to open a new persistent store with the same MOMD as the original file, create a new Managed Object Context, then iterate over all the objects in my database and insert them into the new context.

This will work for simple entities, but the problem is that my model has about 20 entities, many of them with one-to-many and many-to-many relationships. The slightly more complex solution would be to insert every object into the new MOC, and then hold all the new Managed Objects in memory and use them to tie up all the relationships between the objects in a subsequent passes. But it seems like a really messy solution.

Is there a clean, elegant way to achieve this, that might work for any kind of data model, not just a customized solution for my own model, and without having to hold every object in memory at the same time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the persistent store is far and above the easiest way to do this – I'd suggest revisiting your reasons against it or explaining what they are.

Copying objects from one context to another – from one on-disk persistent store to another – doesn't necessarily hold them all in memory at the same time. Core Data can turn them into faults.

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I can't is some limitations with iCloud where you can't just migrate or copy a file and use it with some other iCloud account (or without an iCloud account even).

Comment: How do you get the data from iCloud to begin with?

Comment: That's by using the migratePSC API, but it's proven to be a big memory hog. That's why I want to do it using object-by-object copying, so I can control the memory pressure a little better.